# delete file after sending it android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file

file sends fine but how do I delete it after sending, deleteOnExit() doesn`t work. Maybe I should save it in cache but when I`m trying to do so(with getCacheDir()) file doesn`t sends
any help would be greatly appreciated

```
                String  fileName_Kon;
             fileName_Kon = ((EditText) popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.userInputNameForFile)).getText().toString() + ((TextView) popupWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.dateNameFile)).getText().toString();

                   File sharedir = new File(getFilesDir(), "files");
                if (!sharedir.exists()) sharedir.mkdir();
                String shareName = new String(fileName_Kon);


               try {
                   File shareFile =   File.createTempFile(shareName,".txt",sharedir);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
//shareFile.deleteOnExit();
               try {
                    FileOutputStream flogs = new FileOutputStream(shareFile);
                   
                        flogs.write("text").getBytes());
                    
                    flogs.flush();
                    flogs.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
          
              emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, AUTHORITY, shareFile);
                ArrayList uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                uris.add(contentUri);
                emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send..."));
```

Comment: Sorry, but where is this about?

Comment: As @blackapps indicated, it's not very clear: exactly what your code is intended to achieve, what sort of problem you're having (exception, error, error message, failure, etc.?), how your problem is related to android-studio, or what you may have tried to resolve the issue. Please take a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), update your question to add clarity and detail, or it will likely be closed as: **Needs details or clarity**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait until activity of the application you send file to finished and delete file after that.

1. Register request code (as field of the class):

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 10;
```

2. Keep file in app private folder:

```
try {
  File shareFile = new File(sharedir, shareName + ".txt");
  shareFile.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

// write to file, as you do in the snippet
```

3. Start Activity with result to be notified when user comes back from the selected app:

```
MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
  Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send..."), 
  REQUEST_CODE
);
```

4. Execute action on result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
     // delete file here
     File shareFile = new File(sharedir, shareName + ".txt");
     if (shareFile.exists()) {
        shareFile.delete();
     }
  }
}
```